# Requests Post object Python

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to make a request to a given endpoint:

```py
requests.post(url = accessTokenUrl, json = body, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(clientId, clientSecret))
```

and keep getting a 400 back from the server.

I want to be able to print the object that requests.post(params) builds *BEFORE* it sends; it would look something like this when printed:

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic Y134123123441324dfas1YzI4Nzg5NTE0
Accept: */*
Host: test-lm.lb.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 46

Request Body
grant_type: "client_credentials"
scope: "test-admin"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: request.headers, request.body or request.__dict__

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: `resp = request.post()` then do `resp.__dict__` you can see all the thing related to request